# a soul-tragedy of no mean proportion

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does the part in bold mean?

> In one authorial interruption, Robins
> generalizes about the experience of a woman writer in her
> day: Who shall not say there was no element of courage and
> of steadfast strength in the woman who, year in, year out,
> sat chained to her writing-table, ceaselessly commemorating
> the futile and inept, leaving behind her day by day
> upon that sacrificial altar some fragment of youth and
> health, some shred of hope, some dead illusion. To sit
> down daily to the task of being George Eliot, and to rise
> up "the average lady-novelist" to the end, must, even if
> only dimly comprehended, **be a soul-tragedy of no mean
> proportion**.
>
> — Elaine Showalter, [A Literature of Their Own: British Women Novelists from Bronte to Lessing](https://books.google.ca/books?id=bkT_DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA105&lpg=PA105&dq=%22As%20Charlotte%20Bronte%20and%20George%20Eliot%20increasingly%20came%22&source=bl&ots=RqZ0skA88W&sig=ACfU3U3YbLQkSpIaEHWHdIVV0YonHH7oiA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjSwaCtr7TtAhXKjVkKHbx9BBkQ6AEwAnoECAIQAg#v=onepage&q=%22As%20Charlotte%20Bronte%20and%20George%20Eliot%20increasingly%20came%22&f=false), 2020

Comment: 'Soul-tragedy' is a nonce compound, meaning a tragedy involving the author's inner life rather than outward disaster: constant heart-ache.

Comment: Thank you. Does "mean" mean malicious here?

Comment: No, 'paltry', 'insignificant'. // Oh, and the hyphen has disappeared from 'heartache'. Apologies.

Comment: This sounded like a Teutonism to me, and indeed, searching for *Seelentragödie*, the word is clearly in circulation in German. It seems to be a term from literary theory.

Comment: *It's very tragic* is conveyed here in *understatement*. Instead of writing that the tragedy is great, it says it's not small.

Comment: A typical usage is in ['no mean feat'](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/no+mean+feat). *To be a considerably great, difficult, or noteworthy achievement or outcome.* Also see ['no mean...'](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/be+no+mean...). Here [**mean**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/mean) means small or poor.